# How to prove that the jinn didnt write the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, jinn, doubts

A person was suffering from doubts and he asked "What if the jinn authored the Qur'an?". How to prove that it is false?

Comment: Do the Jinn speak Arabic? Do they write books? I think these are questions one should ask prior to asking whether they are able to write the qur'an a'dhu bil-Lahi Mina-Shaytani ar-Rajeem. The qur'an is considered a third kind of Arabic literature beside poetry and prose because it falls on neither of these categories.

Comment: Please do not make more work for others by vandalizing your posts.

Comment: If you no longer want your name associated with this post, you can request disassociation: Instructions can be found in the meta post https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/132874. Vandalizing your posts like this is unacceptable behaviour on the site, and an insult to the people who have already taken the time to answer the question.

Comment: Don't completely change your question after it has been answered.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear before: This question has been asked and answered by the community, which means **it is now a community work**. If you think this question should be deleted, you are more than welcome to discuss it on [meta] where the community can be involved in the decision. If you want to ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page. **You do not get to unilaterally decide to undo everybody else's work by deleting, destroying or changing this question just because you no longer like it.**

Comment: This question can create doubts about Islam and the answers are not enough. And if doubts enter your heart it's hard, extremely hard to stop them I don't think that stopping me from vandalizing it is better than causing a person to go to hell because of not believe in Islam.

Answer (score 1):

Why would a jinn write about God and good things. And why would he himself make his own kind inferior to humans. Why would they make the communication between us and them(jinn) forbidden. And why would a jinn make all the human and jinn worship Allah(God).

If jinn had written the quran then he would make us worship himself and not God. That's not the case. Most importantly there is no controdiction in quran and it is scientifically very accurate.

Lastly quran itself say that it is from Allah(God) not from Prophet Muhammad(saw) and not from any human or jinn.

**Hope you understood**

Comment: There's some logic in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the quran and ponder over it, you realize it is not possible for any human or jinn to produce such a recital. Its too perfect, with manifest verses, simlatudes, muture wisdom. This is why it says in the Quran, if the whole of minkind and jinn got together they could not produce it. In fact the Quran challenges anyone to even produce 1 chapter like the chapters in the Quran:

And if ye are in doubt as to what We have revealed from time to time to Our servant, then produce a Surah like thereunto; and call your witnesses or helpers (if there are any) besides Allah, if your (doubts) are true. (2:23)

people have tried and no-one has done it.

Now jinn if you ask any raqi are not very clever. Raqi are people that talk to jinns through people afflicted with black magic. So it makes even less sense that jinns made the quran than humans.

Furthermore a raqi will tell you jinns command shameful deeds and they do this a lot. While the Quran tell you to strongly stay away from shameful deeds.

Jinns also lie alot, while the quran if you read it is true and you can see that the one that if has comes froms believes in truth-hood, the truth, rightiousness and is strongly against lying, falsehood and wrongding. So this also is not the charactristics of jinn. THis is why it says in the quran it does not suit the jinn so cannot be from them.

Also muhammad (pbuh) has over 400 narations of miracles other than the Quran that cannot be done by jinns, like when he made it rain heavy 7 days after a drought. The jinns do not have power to control the weather. Any person with experience with jinn/magic will tell you this. Thus if the message of Muhammad (pbuh) was from jinn would Allah give him those miracles.